# Channel API: will presence get a disconnected notification when token expires?

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

I have built an app on the Channel API, using the channel presence urls to keep track of connected clients.

I receive a ping at /_ah/channel/disconnected/ when clients go away. Will I receive a ping if the token expires while the front-end client is connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will. And your front-end client will get an onerror and onclose callback.